# Quotient group concerning $\mathbb Z / 24 \mathbb Z$

Tags: group-theory, quotient-group

Let $G=\mathbb Z / 24 \mathbb Z$ and let $H$ be cyclic subgroup of $G$ generated by class $16+ 24 \mathbb Z$.

The question is whether $G/H$ is cyclic? I don't even know what elements of $G/H$ are supposed to be, classes containing classes? Maybe the fact that $\mathbb Z / 24 \mathbb Z$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{24}$ could help by simplifying things.

Also, what would be the order of $G/H$? By Lagrange's theorem, it should be $|G|/|H|=8$, is that correct? But if I identify $\mathbb Z / 24 \mathbb Z$ with $\mathbb Z_{24}$, I get more than $8$ elements in $G/H$.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think you get more than $8$ elements if you make that identification?

Comment: @DanielLittlewood I thought this is the list of elements in $G/H$ 

$$$$

$[1]+H, [2]+H,...,[23]+H$

Comment: @windircurse, In your notation, how is $[8] + H$ different from $[0] + H$?

Comment: @DWe1 It isn't?, But if I remove $[8]+H, [16]+H$ from the list above, I still have some excess elements?

Feel like I'm missing something fundamental.

Comment: Your list starts repeating. Since $H=\{0,8,16\}$ we have $$ \begin{array}{lll}
 [8]+H & = & [0]+H \\ [9]+H & = & [1]+H \\ [10]+H & = & [2]+H \\ & \vdots \\ [15]+H & = & [7]+H \\ [16]+H & = & [0]+H \\ [17]+H & = & [1]+H \\ [18]+H & = & [2]+H \\ & \vdots \end{array} $$

Comment: @anon thanks, mate. That clarifies that bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we view $G = \mathbb{Z}/24\mathbb{Z}$, we talk about the quotient group of the additive group $\mathbb{Z}$ and a subgroup $24\mathbb{Z}$. Hence, we "mod out" $24$ and set it equivalent to $0$. If we denote $n \mod 24$ as $\bar{n}$,
$$G = \{\bar{0}, \bar{1}, \cdots, \bar{23}\}$$
and has order $24$. Now that we are used to this group, we again take a quotient group with the subgroup $H$, generated by $16 \mod 24$. Hence, $H$ looks like
$$H = \{\bar{0}, \bar{8}, \bar{16}\}.$$

Indeed, $\#G/H$ is then 8, and since $H$ is generated by one element, it is by definition cyclic, hence so is $G/H$

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Every homomorphic image of a cyclic group is cyclic.

Answer (score 1):

$H=\langle 16\rangle =\{[0],[8],16]\}$

Then $|G/H|=8$ and note that quotient group of a cyclic group is cyclic(Just use that $\Bbb Z_{24}/H=\langle [1]+H\rangle$

Answer (score 1):

A quotient of a  cyclic group is necessarily cyclic since being cyclic neans there  is a surjective group homomorphism from $\mathbf Z$ onto the group. So you just have to compose the canonical surjective homomorphism $\;\mathbf Z\twoheadrightarrow G=\mathbf Z/24\mathbf Z $ with  the no less canonical $G\twoheadrightarrow G/H$.

This being said, since $1$ has order $24$ in $\mathbf Z/24\mathbf Z$, $16=16\cdot 1$ has order $\dfrac{24}{\gcd(16,24)}=3$, so that 
$\;|G/H|=\dfrac{24}3=8$.

Finally, observe that 
$$16(\mathbf Z/24\mathbf Z)=(16\mathbf Z+24\mathbf Z)/24\mathbf Z=8\mathbf Z/24\mathbf Z\simeq\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z.$$
In particular, the subgroup generated by $16$ is also generated by $8=-16$.